# Sql query to partition and sum the records grouping by their bill number and Product code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Below are two tables where there are parent bill number like 1, 4 and 8. These parents bill references to nothing/NULL values. They are referenced by one or more child bill number.  For eg parent bill 1 is referenced by child bill 2, 3 and 6.

Table B also has the `bill no` column with prod code with actual service (ST values) and associated service values (SV). SV are the additional cost to ST.
Same ST may occur in multiple bill numbers. Here Bill number is only unique.
For eg, ST1 are in bill number 1 and 8. Also same SV may reference same or different ST.

SV1, SV2 and SV3 are referencing to ST1 corresponding to bill no. 1 and SV2 and SV4 are referencing to ST2 corresponding to bill no.2.

How can we get below expected output?

Table A:

```
    |      bill no        |         ref      |          
    +----------------------------------------+
    |          1          |                  |
    |          2          |         1        |
    |          3          |         1        |
    |          4          |                  |
    |          5          |         4        |
    |          6          |         1        |
    |          7          |         4        |
    |          8          |                  |
    |          9          |         8        |
```

Table B:

```
    |      bill no        |    Prod code     |     cost   |       
    +-----------------------------------------------------+
    |          1          |       ST1        |      10
    |          2          |       SV1        |      20
    |          3          |       SV2        |      30
    |          4          |       ST2        |      10
    |          5          |       SV2        |      20
    |          6          |       SV3        |      30
    |          7          |       SV4        |      40
    |          8          |       ST1        |      50
    |          9          |       SV1        |      10
```

Expected output:

```
    |      bill no        |    Prod code     | ST_cost    |     SV1    |     SV2    |     SV3     |          
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |          1          |       ST1        |      10    |  20        |   30       | 30          |
    |          4          |       ST2        |      10    |  20        |   40       |             |
    |          8          |       ST1        |      50    |  10        |            |             |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that should get you there:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TableA;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableA
(
    BillNumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Reference int NULL
);
GO

INSERT dbo.TableA (BillNumber, Reference)
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES (1,NULL),
             (2,1),    
             (3,1),
             (4,NULL),  
             (5,4),    
             (6,1),  
             (7,4),    
             (8,NULL),     
             (9,8)) AS a(BillNumber, Reference);
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TableB;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TableB
(
    BillNumber int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductCode varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    Cost int NOT NULL
);
GO

INSERT dbo.TableB (BillNumber, ProductCode, Cost)
SELECT BillNumber, ProductCode, Cost
FROM (VALUES (1, 'ST1', 10),
             (2, 'SV1', 20),
             (3, 'SV2', 30),
             (4, 'ST2', 10),
             (5, 'SV2', 20),
             (6, 'SV3', 30),
             (7, 'SV4', 40),
             (8, 'ST1', 50),
             (9, 'SV1', 10)) AS b(BillNumber, ProductCode, Cost);
GO

WITH ParentBills
AS
(
    SELECT b.BillNumber, b.ProductCode, b.Cost AS STCost
    FROM dbo.TableB AS b
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableA AS a
    ON b.BillNumber = a.BillNumber
    WHERE a.Reference IS NULL 
),
SubBills
AS
(
    SELECT pb.BillNumber, pb.ProductCode, pb.STCost, 
           b.ProductCode AS ChildProduct, b.Cost AS ChildCost  
    FROM ParentBills AS pb
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableA AS a
    ON a.Reference = pb.BillNumber
    INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS b
    ON b.BillNumber = a.BillNumber
)
SELECT sb.BillNumber, sb.ProductCode, sb.STCost,
       MAX(CASE WHEN sb.ChildProduct = 'SV1' THEN sb.ChildCost END) AS [SV1],
       MAX(CASE WHEN sb.ChildProduct = 'SV2' THEN sb.ChildCost END) AS [SV2],
       MAX(CASE WHEN sb.ChildProduct = 'SV3' THEN sb.ChildCost END) AS [SV3]
FROM SubBills AS sb
GROUP BY sb.BillNumber, sb.ProductCode, sb.STCost
ORDER BY sb.BillNumber;
```

Comment: There are 1000 of child product like SV1,SV2,SV3,etc.Is there any other way rather than hardcode the value?

Comment: Only by building the statement with dynamic SQL. SQL Server doesn't deal with queries that return unknown numbers of columns like that. It's possible (but very messy) to construct it with dynamic SQL. What people often want is the equivalent of a TRANSFORM statement in Access. But SQL Server doesn't have that.

Comment: Even if you use the PIVOT/UNPIVOT statements, the list of columns is a static list. It can't come from a query unless you build it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that creates you query based on your SV number.
And use "Execute Immediate" to execute the Query String and then "PIPE ROW" to generate the result. 
Check This [PIPE ROW EXAMPLE](http://codethataint.com/blog/pipe-row-oracle-function-example/)

Comment: Dude my database server is sql server.You are talking about oracle functions

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where the "SV1" value comes from on the second row.

But your problem is basically conditional aggregation:

```
with ab as (
      select a.*, b.productcode, b.cost,
             coalesce(a.reference, a.billnumber) as parent_billnumber 
      from a join
           b
           on b.billnumber = a.billnumber
     )
select parent_billnumber,
       max(case when reference is null then productcode end) as st,
       sum(case when reference is null then cost end) as st_cost,
       sum(case when productcode = 'SV1' then cost end) as sv1,
       sum(case when productcode = 'SV2' then cost end) as sv2,
       sum(case when productcode = 'SV3' then cost end) as sv3
from ab 
group by parent_billnumber
order by parent_billnumber;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f1b689a926ee5e3b016b0328462af51) is a db<>fiddle.

Note this works because you have only one level of child relationships.  If there are more, then recursive CTEs are needed.  I would recommend that you ask a *new* question if this is possible.

The CTE doesn't actually add much to the query, so you can also write:

```
select coalesce(a.reference, a.billnumber) as parent_billnumber ,
       max(case when a.reference is null then productcode end) as st,
       sum(case when a.reference is null then b.cost end) as st_cost,
       sum(case when b.productcode = 'SV1' then b.cost end) as sv1,
       sum(case when b.productcode = 'SV2' then b.cost end) as sv2,
       sum(case when b.productcode = 'SV3' then b.cost end) as sv3
from a join
     b
     on b.billnumber = a.billnumber
group by coalesce(a.reference, a.billnumber) 
order by parent_billnumber;
```